# DbUtils ISSUE after downloading jarfile

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbutils

I have installed and extracted the rsX2ml.jar files .Still my eclipse program is displaying error for the DbUtils code line of cannot be resolved .I have removed and imported the jar files again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
So, did you import `DbUtils` (which I wrote incidentally)?

Comment: sorry for causing  the inconvenience ,Yes i did import the jar file of DbUtils ,the error shows that it sill could not be resolved.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @g00se Windows 10 Pro ,i have tried multiple times on removing the jar files and inserting back still i get the error message of DbUtils.

Comment: Please open cmd.exe, change to the project directory and post the output (*as text*) of `dir /s/b`

Comment: @g00se i am unable to paste it in text format, is there other way through which i could send you the screenshot of dir of project?

Comment: No i need that output. You must learn how to copy and paste from cmd.exe. It's perfectly possible

Comment: In Stack Q/A editor use 'code' markdown (click-span or otherwise select the text and click the {} button or control K, or indent each line 4 spaces, or put a line of 3 backticks before and after) for _all_ formatted data: console input and output and data file contents, not just code (@g00se)